# how separate each string in csv line to lines

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

we want to separate each string in csv line to lines

example of line ( could be other line , with the same concept  )

```
machine23,machine094,machine73,machine83
```

so we try this

```
echo machine23,machine094,machine73,machine83 |awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%-20s", $i};printf "\n"}'
```

but we get

```
machine23   machine094  machine7  machine83
```

instead to get the following expected results

```
machine23
machine094 
machine7 
machine83
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Your solution almost works! The `\n` needs to be inside the loop; see the latest revision to [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537906/87770) below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ echo machine23,machine094,machine73,machine83 | tr ',' '\n'
machine23
machine094
machine73
machine83
```

or if you really wanted to do it in awk (perhaps because you want to do further processing in awk):

```
$ echo machine23,machine094,machine73,machine83 | \
  awk -F',' -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1;$0=$0;print}'
machine23
machine094
machine73
machine83
```

This uses a neat awk trick where if you change any field (even by setting it equal to itself, as in `$1=$`) and then set `$0=$0`, awk will reformat the entire input line - replacing the original field separators  (`FS`, a comma in this case) with the output field separator (`OFS`, a newline in this case).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `If you don't reformat it with $0=$0 then you'll have an empty field (and its field separator) in the output.`. `$0=$0` is to re-split the record into fields, you don't want to do that in this case as it'll combine all 4 fields into 1 since the `$1=$1` replaced all FS (`,`) values with OFSs (`\n`) so re-splitting the record afterwards won't find any FSs to split on. `$0=$0` will never affect the output or any values in the record though, it ONLY re-does field splitting.

Comment: @EdMorton   I was going to say compare the output of blahblahblah, but then I tested it and it seems that either I misremembered it (although i'm *certain* i've used this trick in the past because there isn't/wasn't any other trivial way of actually deleting - as opposed to setting it to the empty string - a field in awk) or *undocumented behaviour* has changed in some recent version.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at - the case you're remembering where you can remove a deleted field is `echo 'a b c' | awk '{$2="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1'`. First you delete the field contents, then you re-split (and now the 2 blanks between a and c are one FS so 3 fields are now 2), then you recombine $0 changing FSs (including the 2 contiguous blanks) to OFSs (a single blank).

Comment: yep, that's it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, in the spirit of teaching, here's a fixed version of your own logic (wrapped & spaced for legibility):

```
$ echo machine23,machine094,machine73,machine83 \
    |awk -F"," '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { printf "%-20s\n", $i } }'
machine23           
machine094          
machine73           
machine83
```

Because you used `%-20s`, this adds a bit of trailing white space (select the above output to see it), but all I did was move the `printf "\n"` into the `printf` inside the `for` loop.

Since your version had so little white space, here's a [code-golfed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) solution using your logic:

```
echo machine23,machine094,machine73,machine83|awk -F, '{while(i<NF)print$++i}'
```

Here's a field-agnostic awk solution using global replacement without needing a loop:

```
$ echo machine23,machine094,machine73,machine83 |awk '{ gsub(/,/,"\n"); print }'
machine23
machine094
machine73
machine83
```

This mimics the following sed solution:

```
$ echo machine23,machine094,machine73,machine83 |sed 's/,/\n/g'
machine23
machine094
machine73
machine83
```

Both of the above simply replace commas with newlines, just like [cas's tr solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537872/87770).

Here's a grep solution:

```
$ echo machine23,machine094,machine73,machine83 |grep -o '[^,]*'
machine23
machine094
machine73
machine83
```

This has grep show only (`-o`) matching non-comma text, with each item on its own line.